# How to Install OpenCart in subdirectory?

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

I have a godaddy web hosting, with more domains. Let's say shopping.com points to `shopping` folder. After installing OpenCart I can see no .htaccess.txt file in order to edit `RewriteBase /`. And while accessing the web page it redirects me to install which lets me upgrade. I tried downloading a default OpenCart .htaccess file from web, but then I get 403 error. Anyone knows what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to `chmod 755 .htaccess` as the server did not have access to the file.
Hope it helps someone else to solve their issue.